# Open settings when use click on particular word in text

Tags: swiftui

Below is the code I am using :

```
Text("Welcome! If you need help locating it, click [here](Open Settings)to go to settings and copy the number.")
```

I can open any URL in safari, but how can I open :

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
 

    Text("Welcome! If you need help locating it, click [here](https://www.capitalone.com)to go to settings and copy the number.")
```

I can not use attributed string.

Comment: what is the problem of using an Attributed string?

Comment: Use custom scheme that is registered in your app, so when clicked the url will be directed to the app and you can handle it as you wish in `onOpenURL`.